# Form not showing up in page

Tags: python, django

Hey guys need a little help cant seem to figure it out. For some reason my form won't show up in my page please see code below.

forms.py

```
class NewEntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label = "Title")
    content = forms.CharField(label = "Body")
```

views.py

```
def new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewEntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['body']
            content = markdown2.markdown(title)
            filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
            if default_storage.exists(filename):
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
                    "error":'A file with this title already exists.'
                })
            else:
                util.save_entry(title, content)
                return redirect('entry_page', title=title)
    else:
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/new.html', {'form':NewEntryForm()})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search"),
    path("wiki/new", views.new, name="new")
]
```

new.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
  Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <form class="" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">

  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

[Page output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qkRc.png)

[cli output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAXbP.png)

Comment: You showed us the `results.html` page, but the `new()` view doesn't render that page...

Comment: I just labeled it wrong but the code was right. Nevertheless, I corrected the mistake.

Comment: What is the content of 'encyclopedia/layout.html'?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```py
def new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewEntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # ...
    else:
        form = NewEntryForm()
        
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/new.html', {'form': form})
```

Logically what you missed in this part (inside the default storage thing)

```py
return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
    "error": 'A file with this title already exists.'
})
```

is that you rendered the *errors* but you didn't include the actual form. Technically, you can also fix it like this example below, but I'd just prefer to do it how the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view) gave us.

```py
return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
    "error": 'A file with this title already exists.',
    "form": form    # you didn't include your form in the inner return
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my urls.py file. The url that takes a str argument was validating to a blank page because Django checks urls in sequence. I just moved the str url to the bottom of urls.py and it worked.